# How do I return only the integer sum of Measure-Object in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

If I run the following command in PowerShell, it will return to me an object with the sum of the WorkingSet property:

```
PS > get-process chrome | measure-object WorkingSet -sum

Count    : 36
Average  :
Sum      : 2377129984
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : WorkingSet
```

If I want to return just the `Sum` value, the only way I've found to do it is:

```
PS > $a = get-process chrome | measure-object WorkingSet -sum
PS > $a.Sum
2359980032
```

Is there a way to pipe the original command to some other command so that I return the integer in a single step? Something like this:

```
PS > get-process chrome | measure-object WorkingSet -sum | {some other command}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, use [Select-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx):

```
Get-Process chrome | Measure-Object WorkingSet -sum | Select-Object -expand Sum
```

Select-Object is used when one needs only some properties from the original object. It creates a new object and copies the desired properties to the new one.

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -property ProcessName, Handles
```

In case you need to extract the value (from one property), you use parameter `-expandProperty` instead of `-property`:

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -expand ProcessName
```

Note that you can compute the returned value:

```
get-process | Select-Object -property @{Name='descr'; Expression={"{0} - {1}" -f $_.ProcessName, $_.Handles }}
```

Answer (score 13):

Just use parentheses to enclose the piped command:

```
(get-process chrome | measure-object WorkingSet -sum).sum
```

As a rule, PowerShell treats anything enclosed in parentheses as an object that you can reference by properties/methods.

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
(get-process chrome | measure-object WorkingSet -sum).sum
```