# How do I extract out the primitive value from a more complex object?

Tags: powershell

I'm using Measure-Object with the -Sum tag in powershell to sum together the result of a number of filesizes in a Exchange mailbox database. The result of this operation is an object which just seems to hold a single integer value.

I need to compare this sum to another sum, but I'm told the "sum" object does not implement "IComparable". So what I really need is to get at that single integer value inside this object returned from the "Measure-Object" command.

Example (for testing):

> [PS] >$size1 = Get-MailboxStatistics -Database Some\Exchange\Database | select-object {$*.TotalItemSize/1MB} | Measure-Object -Property '$*.TotalItemSize/1MB' -Sum | Select Sum
>
> [PS] >$size2 = Get-MailboxStatistics -Database Someother\Exchange\Database | select-object {$*.TotalItemSize/1MB} | Measure-Object -Property '$*.TotalItemSize/1MB' -Sum | Select Sum

**Doesn't work:**

> echo ($size1 -lt $size2)

Comment: Note that it should be $_.TotalItemSize/1MB, the underscore is being removed from the question.

Comment: Also note: This is related but does not (seem?) to answer my query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408111/how-do-i-return-only-the-integer-sum-of-measure-object-in-powershell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Get-MailboxStatistics -Database Some\Exchange\Database | 
 foreach {$size1 += $_.totalitemsize.value.tobytes()/1mb}
```

Comment: Interesting thanks. Makes me wonder what the point of .Sum is then.

Comment: measure-object just doesn't work right on the ByteQuantifiedSize types that get-mailboxstatistics returns for size properties.

Answer (score 2):

This returns a GenericMeasureInfo object which has a property that contains the actual sum. Try `echo ($size1.Sum -lt $size2.Sum)`.

Comment: Piping things to Get-Member is often helpful for stuff like this. So is dumping them in a variable and then doing $var.GetType().